# My Swiper app doesn't apply fade effect in React

Tags: reactjs, swiper.js, fade

So, here is my code below, I randomly set the images as backgrounds, everything works except `fade` effect. However it works if I drag the slide with a mouse but when I press `navigation` button, nothing happens. Not nothing actually - it allows to move to the next slide once, and then nothing happanes. The transition from that first slide by `navigation` button is going without `fade` effect as well.

```
import React from 'react';
import SwiperImagesStack from './media/swiper-images/SwiperImagesIndex';
import SwiperTexts from './SlideTexts';
import './css/MainSwiper.css';
import { Navigation, Pagination, EffectFade, Autoplay, A11y, } from 'swiper';
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide} from 'swiper/react';

import 'swiper/css';
import 'swiper/css/navigation';
import 'swiper/css/pagination';
import 'swiper/css/scrollbar';


export default function MainSwiper() {
  const CaseFotos = [19, 2, 3, 3, 5, 8, 8, 2, 1, 2, 4, 5, 4, 7, 18, 4, 5, 3, 6, 4, 3, 5];
  
   const mybg = (m, index) => {
    if (index === 0) {
      if ([10, 13].includes(m)) {
        return ({ backgroundImage: `url('${SwiperImagesStack[index][m]}')`,
                  justifyContent: 'flex-end',
                  alignItems: 'flex-end' });
        }
      else if ([1, 4, 6, 11, 12, 15, 17, 18].includes(m)) {
        return ({ backgroundImage: `url('${SwiperImagesStack[index][m]}')`,
                  justifyContent: 'flex-start',
                  alignItems: 'flex-end' });
        }
      else if ( m === 16) {
        return ({ backgroundImage: `url('${SwiperImagesStack[index][m]}')`,
                  justifyContent: 'flex-end', 
                  alignItems: 'flex-start' });
      }
      else {
        return ({ backgroundImage: `url('${SwiperImagesStack[index][m]}')` });
      }
    }
    else {
      return ({ backgroundImage: `url('${SwiperImagesStack[index][m]}')`,
    color: 'white' });
    }
  }


  return (
  
    <Swiper
        spaceBetween={30}
        slidesPerView={1}
        navigation={true}
        effect={"fade"}
        speed={1500}
        autoplay={{delay: 5500}}
        pagination={{
        clickable: true,
        }}
        loop={true}
        modules={[Navigation, Pagination, Autoplay, A11y, EffectFade]}
        className="MainSwiper"
      >
          
        {CaseFotos.map((n, index) => 
          <SwiperSlide className='SwiperSlide' key={`slide${index}`} id={`case${index}`} style={mybg(Math.floor(Math.random() * (n-1)), index)} >
            <div className='categoryWrapper'>
              <h2 className="case-text">
                <strong> {`${SwiperTexts[index]}`} </strong>
                  <button>
                    <span>
                      <span>
                        <span data-attr-span="See how">
                          See how
                        </span>
                    </span>
                    </span>
                  </button>
              </h2>
            </div>
          </SwiperSlide>)
        }
    </Swiper> 
  );
}
```

I've tried [Swiper demo for fade in React](https://codesandbox.io/s/v1c96y?file=/src/App.jsx), I've tried to replace the order of iported modules and components, nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

Just add

`import "swiper/css/effect-fade";"` !!!!